# Are there any universally accepted or non-Abrahamic based records in history that have mentions of longevity of prophets?

Tags: reference-request, chronology, extra-biblical, patriarchs

Reading from [here](http://blog.adw.org/2017/02/noah-really-live-950/) and [Genesis 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen%205&version=ESV) we see that there are mentions of longevity among prophets:

- Adam – 930
- Seth – 912
- Enosh – 905
- Jared – 962
- Methuselah – 969
- Noah – 950
- Shem – 600
- Eber – 464
- Abraham – 175
- Moses – 120

My question is are there any **other** historical books (a book that has nothing to do with Abrahamic religions) that mention any of these ages? Basically what I'm asking was there any non-religious, secular book written that cites these ages? Or a book written by Abrahamic followers that is still somewhat *universally* accepted?

I personally consider the Old and New Testament as (partially history) books that can be referenced but consider that out of the scope of the question.

Comment: The requirement "book accepted also by non-Christians or a book that had nothing to do with Abrahamic religions" is not clear. Jewish texts such as the Mishnah and Talmud are unsurprisingly accepted by Jewish traditions but are clearly related to 'Abrahamic religions'. Do they meet your criteria?

Comment: @bradimus see my edit. But to answer your question: No Jewish text are not an answer to my question

Comment: "Abrahamic religion" is an umbrella term for religions whose patriarch is Abraham. So the way I understand it is that it includes scriptures (Tanakh, Quran) and tradition. In other words, non-Abrahamic religions.

Comment: It sounds like this is about [history](https://history.stackexchange.com/) rather than about Christianity. Perhaps you should ask on that site.

Comment: Josephus considered himself a historian. Are his works 'non-religious, secular'? I think you may run into trouble looking for an ancient text that meets the modern definition of secular.

Comment: Well, it's a shame you edited your post asking instead for secular, nonreligious texts while I offered an answer for non-Abrahamic faiths. How far back are you looking? You'd be hard-pressed to find religion divorced from politics or society the further back you go.

Comment: I am curious about an assumption in your question: just how many people do you think were literate back then, and thus from where would you suspect that a written record of Anything is available?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden I'm looking for Christian related information from non-Christian sources. It's related to both sites, as both can answer. I think I'll have to create another question specifically for them.

Comment: @Meaquidemsententia I don't want to go back that much...but anything from 500-2500 years works. I just want it to be something that is universally accepted as a work of history and it would be hard for someone to say "no, this book isn't accepted...since it's written by someone who was biased etc." Unless there are some text written by Abrahamic followers that are *universally* accepted. FYI I just edited the question

Comment: Those guys are usually called the patriarchs, not prophets...

Comment: 500-2500 years seems a strange criteria. What sort of primary source are you expecting there to be? Someone writing 500 years ago could not accurately report on this without relying on a primary source - the Bible is one, what you're after is a report of these ages that uses a different one. The answer you've already been given, the Sumerian kings list, is why many people believe that at the time, the ANE culture didn't record literal lifespans but exaggerated them to confer status. You may not find any other primary sources if lifespan was defined in-house rather than based on objective fact

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in the Sumerian King List. These kings lived for centuries before a flood.

> When kingship was lowered from heaven, kingship was [first] in Eridu. [In] Eridu, A-lulim [became] king and ruled 28,800 years. Alagar ruled 36,000 years. Two kings [thus] ruled it for 64,800 years. I drop [the topic] Eridu [because] its kingship was brought to Bad-tibira. [In] Bad-tibira, En-men-lu Ana ruled 43,200 years. (Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament, Pritchard, p. 265)

Comment: This answer would be improved if you can show a more coherent linkage between the prophets asked about in the question and the records you cite.

Comment: Hm. That could be very difficult, if not impossible. By prophet, I take it that you and the OP mean one who speaks the words given by a god. The connection between gods and kings in the ANE should suffice. Or I'd hope. For example, a pharaoh would be thought as an avatar for a god like Ra. I also recall Psalm 45 where the imagery of the king going to battle was given the necessary tools for battle. When I have better access online later, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I just realized that the Q was edited and presented you with a different problem to solve.  Hmm, not sure where this is going.

Comment: The Sumerian Kings list is in my view, definitely the best similar contemporary source. It might cause a problem if your aim is to prove that the recorded ages are literal lifespans though, purely because of the massive lifespans even compared to the ones recorded in Genesis. It's more supportive of the idea that the way people recorded lifespans in this time was exaggerated as a means of conferring status, and therefore that the lifespans in genesis need not necessarily be taken literally.